# Generate a .flo file for optical flow

Tags: opticalflow

I am trying to train a CNN network on optical flow. And I need to generate my one frames with the .flo ground truth. However, I don't know how to generate the flo files. So, my question is: How can I generate a ground true optical flow file .flo?

Answer (score 1):

Generating ground-thruth by your own is almoust imposibble. But you can used the ground-thruth provided by the [Middlebury](http://vision.middlebury.edu/flow/), [SINTEL](http://sintel.is.tue.mpg.de/) or [KITTI](http://www.cvlibs.net/datasets/kitti/eval_stereo_flow_detail.php?benchmark=flow&error=3&eval=all&result=908de184511a21fa6b16f5393eb558cd05201d23). In order to estimate your own optical flow fields i would suggest to used OpenCV 3.0 or higher and download the contribution git repo. The repo includes a function to save optical flow fields in the .flo format.